# Setting a mock location on a real Android device with Appium

Tags: java, android, gps, location, appium

I am trying to set a mock location using Appium on a real device. This is what I currently have:

```
Location loc = new Location(40.7142408,-73.7785652,29);
driver.setLocation(loc);
```

It doesn't seem to work. Any ideas? I have read various comments online, some saying it only works on an emulator and some saying it should work on a real device. Unless I am going about it the wrong way?